# Filtering questions based on my Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, questions, tag-watching

Is there a way to filter [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) based on my Favorite Tags? (not searching)

Comment: Your favourites get highlighted, the ignored ones get hidden. Do you want more than that?

Comment: I want to focus only on my Favourite Tags -- I can't see the merit of showing me questions about matters that I don't know.

Comment: Sometimes you'll see mis-tagged things you do know about or learn something interesting. It's easy enough to just read the highlighted titles though.

Comment: I feel your pain. I click and click, thinking something good will happen, but I just keep coming back to that Great Page O' Tags. Have yet to figure out what "Favorite Tags" is good for. I just want to see the new questions with my favorite tags. Irritates my sensitive brains.

Comment: Just press the big StackOverflow logo on top to see relevant questions. Almost all the questions there are from my favorite tags. Maybe because I chose Android, Java and git which happen to be popular tags. Right now I see 5 questions on the whole page that do not contain any of my favorite tags.Some of which also seem interesting.

Comment: @miva2 - this used to be true, but now the majority of questions are from things not tagged with any of my watched tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will do it

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine

Comment: Not really what I intended, @Ramaraj, I don't want to *search* tag by tag, I want some way to see the see questions of my Favourites Tags.

Comment: Actually, you were right, @Ramaraj, thank you! And I am really sorry for not understanding what you said before.

Comment: FYI [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307564/266819) restricts it to questions, only. You basically just need to change it to this: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aquestion`

Comment: I got it, @Kayce (and I up-voted your reply), but Ramaraj answered in 2017; furthermore (and I don't know why), his suggestion brings the newest questions, while all posts returned by your suggestion are already answered.

Comment: Just trying to help, it’s totally fair that you accepted his, I’m just pointing out the solution to something that made his solution less useful to me. Interesting point about mine returning answered questions only.

Answer (score 16):

There are two options that may be helpful:

### Tag Sets

[This page](http://stackexchange.com/tagsets) would provide with the feed of all questions based on your user fav tags. You may create your own tag sets.

Further reading: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

### Custom URLs

Although tag filtering did not work well for me, it seems one can use customized URL to make SO engine properly associate tags with OR operation. This link seems to be quite self-explanatory: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/'c%23'%20or%20'f%23'`

Both approaches also support RSS which seems very useful if there are many of those. I have recently eliminated a whole set of individual per-tag subscriptions by replacing all those with a single one.

Comment: in the Tag Sets, is it possible to view only questions with favorite tags *and* which are not ignored?  Is it possible to reach the `/tagged/` URL via html links?

Comment: @cirosantilli I couldn't accomplish that.

Answer (score 5):

Building off of Ramaraj's helpful answer, this query restricts it to questions, only:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Please refer to my comment above, on @Ramaraj.

Comment: Actually, the link I’ve provided does do what you want. It lists all of the questions of your favorite tags.

Comment: You are right, Kayce, thank you for the information and I'm sorry for not understanding what you and Ramaraj said.