# Filter view to show only Favorite Tags

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering questions based on my Favorite Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131810/filtering-questions-based-on-my-favorite-tags)

Is it possible to get a view of only favorite tags as a default display?

Comment: I was wrong earlier. You can search by specifying your favorite tags with OR operator, but the syntax is weird. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2 . For example: `[c][or][c++][or][java]`. I don't think SO has a one-click solution for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you've constructed that search, e.g.:

```
[c][or][c++][or][java]
```

You should end up with a URL like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b%20or%20java
```

Now, bookmark or favorite that URL. Voila! One-click access to a search of all your favorite tags. Note that you can also use wildcards, e.g.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*+or+vb.net
```

This will return all questions tagged with vb.net or any tag that starts with `sql-server`. Just note that trying to do this from the search box:

```
[sql-server*][or][vb.net]
```

Will actually end up without the asterisk:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+or+vb.net
```

(That is a much more restrictive search.)